# Giving a UITextField, in a custom UITableViewCell, the proper text color when the cell is highlighted/selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` of style `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`. It has a `UITextField` in it.

Whenever the cell is highlighted/selected (i.e. has a blue background), I want the `UITextField` to have a white color, just like the built-in labels do automatically.

This includes, of course, making sure the color of the text field is correct while the “white to blue” or “blue to white” fading animation of the background color is taking place.

How do I properly accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to make a subclass of the table view cell, and override `setSelected:animated:`

in this method you would change the text colour of the field to what you want, depending on the selected flag

to animate you would just put inside an animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3f animations:^{
    field.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}];
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the cell is often highlighted before it is actually selected. I would have to somehow take into account the interplay of the setHighlighted and setSelected methods, I think...

Comment: definitely, somewhere in the apple guides is a good description of how selected and highlighted work together (google is failing me, maybe it was in a book?) but you would need to use both to get a perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

As the cell is 'custom', I presume that you have created a subclass.

Firstly, `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` is not a UITableViewCellStyle, its a selection style, therefore it should not be used in the `-init` method, but can be as its value will be the same as a `UITableViewCellStyle`.

Furthermore, in order to edit the cell upon selection, you need to override the `-setSelected:animated:` method. Moreover, you need to set the cell's textField's `textColor` variable to white upon selection and vice-versa, blue.

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL) selected animated:(BOOL) animated {

    self.textField.textColor = (selected == YES ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blueColor]);

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];        

}
```

Otherwise, it may be best to call a method in the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) _tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) _indexPath {

    [self rowSelected:_indexPath];

}

- (void) rowSelected:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isSelected = cell.isSelected;
    [(UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag] setTextColor:(isSelected == YES ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blueColor])];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you designed your custom cell in Interface Builder, then the UITextField has a 'Highlighted' property in the Attributes Inspector that defaults to black. Set that to white and the text colour changes on touch down.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In your .h file
```

NSIndexPath *selectedIP;

//in.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  


    if (nil ==cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

     if (indexPath == selectedIP) {
        textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else{
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSIndexPath *temp = selectedIP;
    selectedIP = nil;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:temp] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    selectedIP = indexPath;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:selectedIP] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


}
```